# JavaScript security: force deletion of sensitive data

Tags: javascript, cordova, encryption, garbage-collection, immutability

Let's say that my app has a sensitive piece of data, e.g. an encryption key as it is performing local encryption/decryption, and I want the data to be completely flushed from my device's memory upon a logout. This would prevent my phone from falling into the wrong hands and someone accessing the current JS memory to retrieve the decryption key.

[According to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures), all data types in JS are immutable. And, as far as I can tell, there is no way to force garbage collection, especially in the browser. Is there any JS way to ensure that data is completely purged from memory?

If not, would using some other widely supported technology like IndexedDB or WebSQL allow me to purge this data? (I'm assuming that encryption/decryption could be done exclusively at the IndexedDB or WebSQL layer--something that sounds a little crazy to me as I would assume that this data would still reside in a JS string somewhere).

Is a native language like ObjectiveC or JAVA the only way?

Or, am I being paranoid and should assume that anything ready for garbage collection in JS will just be purged in a timely manor automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, strings etc are immutable and maybe stay in memory for a long time until the next GC cycle.

To overcome this, you store the secret in a mutable object. For example, in a basic array:

```
var secret = ['s','e','c','r','e','t'];
```

Now, you can simple erase the information my nulling out the array elements:

```
var len = secret.length
for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
    secret[i] = '0'
}
```

That why many Java API which use deal with passwords and secrets expect a char[] / byte[] array, so that you can null them out afterwards.